# Confused by the version of C# used by Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.39.2) on Windows 10 (1809).  I also installed the OmniSharp C# extension (extension identifier ms-vscode.csharp, version 1.21.5).

When I run the command `csc -langversion:?` from the integrated terminal, I get:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.7.3190.0 
>   
> for C# 5
>   
> warning CS2008: No source files specified
>   
> error CS1617: Invalid option
>   '?' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default

But when I run `csc.exe` from a Windows command line outside of VS Code, specifying a full path like so:

```
C:\Users\myaccount\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5\
    .omnisharp\1.34.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe -langversion:?
```

I get:

> Supported language versions: 
>   
> default
>   
> 1
>   
> 2
>   
> 3
>   
> 4
>   
> 5
>   
> 6
>   
> 7.0 (default)
>   
> 7.1
>   
> 7.2
>   
> 7.3 (latest)
>   
> latest

I understand that VS Code's terminal may be picking up a different version of `csc.exe`, but why the discrepancy, and how do I configure VS Code so that I can use the latest C# compiler?

**EDIT:**

I guess what really perplexes me is why VS Code is not using the `csc.exe` that is installed under its very own directory structure (i.e. under .vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5...).

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but have you run the full command ( `~\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5\.omnisharp\1.34.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe -langversion:?`) from the VS Code terminal? or the short version (`csc -langversion:?`) from a normal command line?

Comment: When I run `csc -langversion:?` from a VS2019 PowerShell I getup to and including 8.0. This is running `C:\VS2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\csc.exe`. From a default PowerShell profile, `csc,exe` isn't found. So it all depends on the profile being used, and what folders are listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @Richard Just tried it using PowerShell, and I got the same output as that from VS Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `csc -langversion:?`, whichever version of the compiler is found via the `PATH` environment variable is being is being run. However, when you run `~\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5\.omnisharp\1.34.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe -langversion:?` the version of the compiler that the csharp extension is using is being run. These will not be the same copy/version of `csc.exe`.

The terminal in VS Code (either CMD or Powershell) are not special versions of these, they don't have any extra environment variables set, so you should see the same results either way.

To remedy the discrepancy either, install the latest version of the compiler on to your system, or update your `PATH` settings to include `~\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.5\.omnisharp\1.34.5\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\` before any other version of `csc.exe`.

Once you've done this, relaunch both VS Code and the windows command line and the results should be identical.

Comment: Thank you.  But why doesn't the OmniSharp extension override the PATH?  After all, by installing that extension, isn't the VS Code user saying "give me the latest you've got"?

Comment: **"The terminal in VS Code is not special"** -- you are right, that's the critical part of your answer.